How to obtain cropping information using ImageCrop[]?
When we use ImageCrop[i] it crops the image i automatically. Can we obtain information like the coordinates where the crop happened?

Documentation for ImageCrop > Possible Issues: Detect the border using BorderDimensions and crop it using ImagePad.

I don't know how to get the crop coordinates from/during the crop process directly, but you can do other things to figure it out. For example, you can use ImageAlign with the before and after images. You can make it more obvious by highlighting the background:
ImageAlign[original, cropped, Background -> Red]

From that I suppose you could analyze the data and look for the edges of the red region.
There is probably a way to look at the original image and predict where the crop will occur, but I don't think it's as simple as it might seem, because I think there is some "slop" to the background matching.

I often have this problem when I do manual cropping.
FindGeometricTransform[] does the job nicely  :
imageOriginal = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House2"}];
imgCropped = ImageCrop[imageOriginal, 200]

geomTransform = FindGeometricTransform[imageOriginal, imgCropped][[2]];
ImageTrim[imageOriginal, 
 geomTransform /@ {{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[imgCropped]}]  

image original (=image full) :

image cropped :

Image programatically retrieved :

